# Check if object exists in an array before pushing

Tags: javascript, mvvm

I have an empty array and a selectable tree, and every time when the user is checking or un-checking a node I'm pushing the node's id and if the checkbox is true or false.

But right now if the user will check and then un-check a node there will be two objects in the array of the same node how can i make sure that doesn't happen?

```
//creating empty array

var checkedItems = []; 

//(in kendo observable) on user selection I'm pushing the checked node to array

onItemChecked : function (e) {
    var node = e.sender.dataItem(e.node);
    checkedItems.push({Id: node.Id, IsChecked: node.checked});
},
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can, before pushing a new object, check the presence of an object that has that id.

```
var el = checkedItems.filter(function(el) {
    return el.Id === node.Id;
});

if (el.length) {
    el[0].IsChecked = node.checked;
} else {
   // push a new object
}
```

Comment: @ManoDestra Thanks for updating my lazily-written answer.

Comment: Thank you, all the best.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use an object, which is guaranteed to have unique keys:

```
var checkedItems = {};
onItemChecked : function (e) {
    var node = e.sender.dataItem(e.node);
    checkedItems[node.Id] = node.checked;
},
```

Comment: Beware of the creation of new object's here, as `{}` && `{}` can be added twice to the Set

Comment: I'm using Vohuman's solution, I do need support for old browsers, thanks though!

Comment: @Endless; I couldn't quite parse what you were saying here. Does it have to do with equality of object references? You might be right... I'll take out Set.

Comment: That is what i meant, references

Answer (score 1):

You have a Id which is grate, cuz that can be used for uniqueness. So maybe an array is not the best suited for what you want to accomplish. There are better way to handle it with just plain object (see Mike McCaughan [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38212808/1008999)) and [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

```
var items = new Map
items.set(node.Id, node.checked)

// Removing items is as easy as 
items.remove(node.Id)

// Getting
var checked = items.get(node.Id)

// Then if you want to iterate over them you would do something like:
for (var [key, value] of items.entries()) {
    console.log(key + " = " + value)
}

var values = items.values()
var keys = items.keys()
```

Map's are like a key/value storage, much like object